# How modify Registry permission after install with Inno Setup

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I need to modify the Registry AFTER all the installation occurs, any thought?, thanks.

The `[Registry]` session occurs beforre the first `[Run]`. I need modify the registry AFTER all the runs finished. I am doing this with `setACL.exe` in the last `[Run]`, but I'm looking for something more elegant (scripting).

Comment: After "what" specifically? I would guess that after you run something in the `[Run]` section, but you should tell us! Or what's wrong with using the `[Registry]` section?

Comment: After the last RUN, [Registry] session occurs beforre the first RUN. I need modify the registry AFTER all the runs finished.I am doing this  with setACL.exe in the last run but I looking for something more elegant ( scripting).

Comment: That's probably the most elegant solution you can get.

Comment: Or you can execute the application before the Registry section.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use the [`CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)` step](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged) to implement an action at the end of the installation, it won't help you much. There's no functions in Inno Setup Pascal Script to set Registry permissions. You would have to execute an external utility anyway.

---

Though you do not have to use a 3rd party utility (SetACL). You can apparently use the Windows `regini` command.

See [Change registry permissions via command line (batch file)](https://superuser.com/q/712392/213663).

---

Another option is to execute your application before the `[Registry]` section.

For example, if you are executing some program that you are installing, you can execute them using the [`AfterInstall` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall):

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; AfterInstall: ExecMyProg

[Code]

procedure ExecMyProg;
begin
  if Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\notepad.exe'), '', '',
          SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
  begin
    Log('Executed');
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('Failed to execute');
  end;
end;
```